# Powershell - False, but sometimes only

Tags: powershell, recursion, conditional-statements

I'm in trouble here. `newPath` is a parameter of the function `analyse` which is written here. I have problems with my conditions...

The objective is to write every address in the .txt if it isn't there yet and if `mSize` (result from a working function) is greater than `seuil` (threshold). "seuil" equals 0 here. I'm matching the code in a folder, and every folder after this one is analysed.

Problem is, it works fine... For 2 addresses only.
I dont get it, when I launch the code, only two lines are written. With tests, I think "result" actually takes the null value and I don't know when and why.

```
$result = get-content -Path O:\folder\public\F*******\parcoursArborescence\logs.txt

$test = "start"
$test
cd $newPath
$newPath
$result

$dirSize = [math]::round($(getDirSize)/1048576, 2)
$mSize = [math]::round($(multimediaSize), 2)

if (($result -match [regex]::Escape($newPath + ";") -eq $FALSE)) {
    $testR = $false
}
if (($result -match [regex]::Escape($newPath + ";") -eq $TRUE)) {
    $testR = $true
}

$mSize
$testR



if ($mSize -gt $seuil -and $testR -eq $FALSE) {
    $dataWriting = "writing..."
    $dataWriting
    $data = $newPath + ";" + $dirSize + ";" + $mSize + ";" + $(mmPercent) + ";" +  $(getLastWriting) + ";" + $(getLastAccess)
    $data | out-file -append O:\folder\public\F*******\parcoursArborescence\logs.txt -Encoding ASCII
}
dir |
foreach-object {
    if ($_.PsISContainer -eq $True -and $result -notMatch [regex]::escape($_.fullname + ";")) { 
        $oldPath = $newPath     
        $newPath = $_.fullname  
        analyse $newPath        
    }
    else {
        $oldPath = cd ..\ | get-location
        $newPath = $oldPath
    }
 }
```

Here are some lines of my textfile :

```
O:\folder\public\DataIntegrator;1030.95;812.7;79;08/13/2013 13:28:49;11/25/2015 09:47:28
O:\folder\public\DataIntegrator\package;988.99;810.93;82;08/13/2013 13:28:49;11/25/2015 09:47:28
```

My work is to classify differents types of files. I want the textfile to be full of adresses which guide to heavy folders (where length < "seuil"). The condition i'm working on is supposed not to allow adresses already in the .txt to be written again. These two lines are the only ones working atm ; after this, no address is written. I tried to put some tests values here and there ; the important one (I guess) is the "testR" one. At the beginning, it works and says its value is either true or false. But, I dont know why and when, it begins to say absolutely nothing, letting me guess it gets a null value.

Exemple of newPath : 0:\folder\public\DataIntegrator 
-> Analyses DataIntegrator

EDIT : I modified the code a little. Here it is :
http://pastebin.com/zKaK2ZWX

For the problem, the only lines that matter are the 42 first. Even with all these conditions, testR doesnt change and stays false. It never confirm one of the 2 other conditions. If I switch testR to true, then it will stay true.

Comment: Can you show an example of $newpath and the text file logs.txt? What does _works fine... For 2 addresses only_ mean? I think the logic of your if statements is flawed but I am _really_ not clear on what is going on here so it might be fine. If we can't replicate the problem you are making it hard for us to troubleshoot. I am not saying the answer might not be staring the Community in the face but you are making it a lot harder as there are assumptions we have to make here. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry about that, it's hard for me to write a lot in english because I am french. I'm going to edit it to give more details.

Comment: I use the PS2 version

Comment: Post the first 20 or so lines on PasteBin and give us the link, or put it here.  You're straying from a lot of PowerShell best practice in the way your code is written, which makes it hard to follow (but we'll help you fix it!).  Show me your input file and I'll help you figure this out.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zKaK2ZWX
I modified the code a little. Now, with those tests, if i tell testR to be False and then try to change its value with the conditions, it doesnt. It just stays false. The rest of the code isnt useful, the only problem is this condition (i guess)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I got it.

I did more and more tests about the `-match` condition. It looks like the output isnt a boolean, but a String ; it sends me the lines of `$result` which contain the String `$testPath`, so the result never is either false or true.

But I have a new problem, then. How can I get a boolean out of it ? I need to know if `$result` contains `$testPath`.

Comment: I dont really understand how does work -match. But there, he told me the number of times my string was in the second one. So I just put a condition to ask if the output was greater than 0, and it worked.